# Get property value from dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I am trying to get property value from dynamic object by specifying property name,it works using an index, but I need to pass in a specific property name to get the value [as the name would be stored in the Db and not the index]

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize(jsonText, typeof(object));
data.Response.Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu["PropertyName"]
```

This is the code for converting my jSON to a dynamic class for which I am trying to get values from a specified property

```
public sealed class DynamicJsonConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        return type == typeof(object) ? new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary) : null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(new List<Type>(new[] { typeof(object) })); }
    }

    #region Nested type: DynamicJsonObject

    private sealed class DynamicJsonObject : DynamicObject
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _dictionary;

        public DynamicJsonObject(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
        {
            if (dictionary == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
            _dictionary = dictionary;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("{");
            ToString(sb);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private void ToString(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            var firstInDictionary = true;
            foreach (var pair in _dictionary)
            {
                if (!firstInDictionary)
                    sb.Append(",");
                firstInDictionary = false;
                var value = pair.Value;
                var name = pair.Key;
                if (value is string)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:\"{1}\"", name, value);
                }
                else if (value is IDictionary<string, object>)
                {
                    new DynamicJsonObject((IDictionary<string, object>)value).ToString(sb);
                }
                else if (value is ArrayList)
                {
                    sb.Append(name + ":[");
                    var firstInArray = true;
                    foreach (var arrayValue in (ArrayList)value)
                    {
                        if (!firstInArray)
                            sb.Append(",");
                        firstInArray = false;
                        if (arrayValue is IDictionary<string, object>)
                            new DynamicJsonObject((IDictionary<string, object>)arrayValue).ToString(sb);
                        else if (arrayValue is string)
                            sb.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", arrayValue);
                        else
                            sb.AppendFormat("{0}", arrayValue);

                    }
                    sb.Append("]");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1}", name, value);
                }
            }
            sb.Append("}");
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result))
            {
                // return null to avoid exception.  caller can check for null this way...
                result = null;
                return true;
            }

            result = WrapResultObject(result);
            return true;
        }

        public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
        {
            if (indexes.Length == 1 && indexes[0] != null)
            {
                if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(indexes[0].ToString(), out result))
                {
                    // return null to avoid exception.  caller can check for null this way...
                    result = null;
                    return true;
                }

                result = WrapResultObject(result);
                return true;
            }

            return base.TryGetIndex(binder, indexes, out result);
        }

        private static object WrapResultObject(object result)
        {
            var dictionary = result as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (dictionary != null)
                return new DynamicJsonObject(dictionary);

            var arrayList = result as ArrayList;
            if (arrayList != null && arrayList.Count > 0)
            {
                return arrayList[0] is IDictionary<string, object>
                    ? new List<object>(arrayList.Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>().Select(x => new DynamicJsonObject(x)))
                    : new List<object>(arrayList.Cast<object>());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is the Json

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Outcome": {
            "KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu": [{
                "Key": "Icon",
                "Value": {
                    "DataType": "System.String",
                    "Field": "Icon",
                    "Value": "O"
                }
            }, {
                "Key": "IconDescription",
                "Value": {
                    "DataType": "System.String",
                    "Field": "IconDescription",
                    "Value": "Old"
                }
            }, {
                "Key": "IconLongDescription",
                "Value": {
                    "DataType": "System.String",
                    "Field": "IconLongDescription",
                    "Value": "Older"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Expecting to get

```
dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize(jsonText, typeof(object));
data.Response.Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu["Icon"].Field.Value
```

Expected value of O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText, typeof(object));
var list = data.Response.Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
var iconNode = list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Key == "Icon");
var valueOfO = iconNode.Value.Value.Value;
```

**Edit: Alternative solution**: Since your data seem to be structured and you are reading hard-coded paths from json, I'll prefer you to make model classes instead of using dynamic objects. Below is One example of working model classes which you can deserialize with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonText)`

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Outcome Outcome { get; set; }
}

public class Outcome
{
    public Keyvalueofstringoutcomepqnxskqu[] KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu { get; set; }
}

public class Keyvalueofstringoutcomepqnxskqu
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Risto, is there a way to achieve this :
data.Response.Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
 by passing in a string of which field to get as an example:

var x = "Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu as IEnumerable<dynamic>";

data.Response.x;

Comment: I don't get your question, how do you want to pass a string?

Comment: If you mean that "Icon" - text as string, you can refactor this as an function, where you pass "Icon" as parameter. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Risto, I cannot do the paste special. The Value class has a Value property on it

Comment: I updated answer, now there are example of model classes (please notice `[JsonProperty("Value")]` - attribute above name-clashing property.